# Can Dictionary.Keys() be re-calculated during its own runtime?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Suppose some `Dictionary` gets modified (an element is added) during a `For Each`-loop of its `Keys` method -- is there a way to ensure that the loop grabs all the elements?

Maybe easier to explain with code:

```
Sub DictionaryKeysCollectionTest()
    Dim a As Dictionary
    Set a = New Dictionary
    a.Add "b", 1
    a.Add "c", 2

    For Each k In a.Keys()
        Debug.Print "Key: " & k

        If k = "c" Then
            Debug.Print "1st count: " & a.Count
            a.Add "a", 0
            Debug.Print "2nd count: " & a.Count
        End If

    Next k
End Sub
```

This will output:

```
Key: b
Key: c
1st count: 2
2nd count: 3
```

We can see at the end that `a` was added to the dictionary (we see the increase in `.Count`), but the loop didn't catch it (we don't see any `a` in the output). I guess because we looped over that part of the dictionary before `a` existed in it.

Is it possible to "re-calculate" the `.Keys()`-part while execution is still inside that loop, so that I can catch also the key `a`?

Comment: No, it's impossible to do it.

Comment: You will need to change to a Do loop.  Once the For initiates it will not expand or contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from comments that the answer is **no**.

Edit: Disregard wrong statements.

Comment: This only works because `a.count` is returning 2 and 0 to 2 is three loops.  It would error if you did not add the third item.  Since the key item number is 0 based the correct method for the for is `For m = 0 To a.Count -1`.  Once again once the `For` is initiated the number of loops are set and no matter what you do in the loop will change that.  If you add two items the second will not be looped with your current setup.  A `Do While` Loop will do what you want but any form of a `For` loop will not.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah... I get what you're saying now. Thanks